# Paste current date in Windows

Tags: windows

I am wondering about solving one simple problem. I would like to when I press some specific key combination that system automatically paste date in format yyyy-mm-dd. Is it possible to do this in some painless way. It should work like in excel when you press CRTL + ;.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this script [AutoHotKey: Paste the current date into any program](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1965837). You also will need [AutoHotKey software](http://www.autohotkey.com/)